# Objective-C property/inheritance/design advice

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns, inheritance, properties

I have a base class `MyDevice`. Also I have a base class `MyDeviceController`:

```
@interface MyDeviceController : NSObject {
    MyDevice* device;
}

@property (retain) MyDevice* device;

@end
```

MyDeviceController has some common logic in setter of device, which I want to keep in subclasses.

I have 2 subclasses of MyDevice:

```
@interface MyAudioDevice : MyDevice

- (void)audioMethod;

@end
```

and

```
@interface MyVideoDevice : MyDevice

- (void)videoMethod;

@end
```

And two subclasses of `MyDeviceController`: `MyVideoDeviceController` and `MyAudioDeviceController` which have to have a `MyVideoDevice` and `MyAudioDevice` as a `device` property.

What is the best way to implement this two subclasses of MyDeviceController? Or may be there is some patter for such cases?

UPDATED

The first solution I found is to redeclare properties in `My[Audio|Video]DeviceController`:

```
@interface MyAudioDeviceController : MyDeviceController

@property (retain) MyAudioDevice* device;

@end
```

and in implementation

```
@implementation MyAudioDeviceController

- (void)setDevice:(MyAudioDevice*)device
{
    NSAssert([device isKindOfClass:[MyAudioDevice class]], @"What's the...?");
    [super setDevice:device];
}

- (MyAudioDevice*)device
{
    return (MyAudioDevice*)[super device];
}

@end
```

The only thing that I don't like in this solution is redefinition of `device` method.

May be there is another solution?

Comment: use an interface (i forget what there called in objective-c) for mydevice(s) and then program to that so the controller can accept any type of device.

Comment: @TomIngram: Protocols is what you're after

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the best solution. The solution is to use the `@dynamic` directive in implementation for property `device`.

```
@interface MyAudioDeviceController : MyDeviceController

@property (retain) MyAudioDevice* device;

@end
```

And implementation:

```
@implementation MyAudioDeviceController

@dynamic device;

- (void)setDevice:(MyAudioDevice*)device
{
    NSAssert([device isKindOfClass:[MyAudioDevice class]], @"What's the...?");
    [super setDevice:device];
}

- (void)someAduioDeviceControllerMethod
{
    [self.device audioMethod];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite `-(void)setDevice:(Device *)device` in your controllers to make sure it only accepts `MyVideoDevice` or `MyAudioDevice`. If you need logic from the general controller, just copy it over.

Comment: Yes, but I also need the `device` method to return `MyAudioDevice`. I also call my `[super setDevice:device]` to avoid duplicated code.
I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

my objective-c is a little off but hopefully this gives you an idea of what I mean in my comment.

"use an interface (i forget what there called in objective-c) for mydevice(s) and then program to that so the controller can accept any type of device."

in theory everything secific to the device should then be private and you use a common interface so ou can have many different concrete devices and not worry about it.

an interface such as

```
@protocol MediaDevice
- void play
- void stop
- void pause
@end
```

implementations

```
@interface AudioDevice : NSObject <MediaDevice> 
@end

@implementation AudioDevice
- void play
{
    [super play]
}
// ...
@end
```

controller

```
@interface DeviceController : NSObject
@property (readwrite, assign) MediaDevice device
@end
```

Comment: But I have different methods for different devices: `videoMethod` for `MyVideoDevice` and `audioMethod` for `MyAudioDevice`, thats why I must use `device` as `MyAudioDevice` in `MyAudioDeviceController`, not as `MyDevice`.